# How to recover lost partitions using a bootable pen drive?

Tags: linux, partitioning, data-recovery, partition-recovery

I have lost all partitions in my laptop's hard disk recently and its now showing as a raw disk.

I have made a bootable pen drive using Ubuntu-12.04 and trying to recover the lost data using TestDisk.

I have successfully installed the software and now when I'm running it, am getting this error.

> testdisk: error while loading shared libraries: libntfs-3g.so.835:
>   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

### State of my System Partitions

> ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l
>
> Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes 255 heads, 63
>   sectors/track, 38913 cylinders, total 625142448 sectors Units =
>   sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512
>   bytes / 512 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>   Disk identifier: 0x00000000
>
> Disk /dev/sda doesn't contain a valid partition table
>
> Disk /dev/sdb: 16.0 GB, 16005464064 bytes 64 heads, 32 sectors/track,
>   15264 cylinders, total 31260672 sectors Units = sectors of 1 * 512 =
>   512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes I/O
>   size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes Disk identifier:
>   0x000789f1
>
> Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
>   /dev/sdb1   *          32    31260671    15630320    c  W95 FAT32
>   (LBA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the `ntfs-3g` package, as in `sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g`.